# Is there a way to access interface like struct field or changing types(different struct) with same field

Tags: go

two/more different sets of data which each data requires it is own struct for different functions, and these two/more sets of data struct share the same field.
how can I combine these two set of data (different types), and can be called by another function which requires access filed from each sets of data.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Plants struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

type Animal struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

type General struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (a *Animal) AnimalHealth() {
    fmt.Printf("Animal: %s is %+v years old who is in healthy condition!\n", a.Name, a.Age)
}

func (p *Plants) PlantsHealth() {
    fmt.Printf("Plants: %s is %+v years old who is in healthy condition!\n", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func (g *General) alive() {
    fmt.Printf("%s is %+v alive. \n", g.Name, g.Age)
}

func main() {
    dog := Animal{
        Name: "luckdog",
        Age:  6,
    }

    flower := Plants{
        Name: "sunflower",
        Age:  5,
    }

    dog.AnimalHealth()    // Output is required.
    flower.PlantsHealth()  // Output is required. 

    var all []interface{}
    all = append(all, dog, flower)
    fmt.Printf("Print out all %s\n", all)

    for _, v := range all {
        fmt.Printf("This is iterate through all value %v\n", v)  //Tested *Animal data and *Plants data are combined. 
//      v.alive()   // *** Output is required, how should access fields, brain is burning.  ***

    }
}
```

make v.alive() works.

Comment: You can embed `General` in `Animal` and `Plants`. You'll also need to declare the common interface. https://play.golang.org/p/6rLQcP0NN4X

Comment: You seem to try to do "classical", inheritance-based OOP in Go. This will not work. Redesign.

Comment: @Volker Thanks for pointing out why is not the right thing to do. Can you also provide some detail which what would be the best practice. maybe some posts from you or you have seen?

Comment: @wzcwts521 I do not have literature available which addresses your problem, but think about it like this: Inheritance in traditional OOP (tOOP) serves two purpose a) polymorphism (you can put Dogs and Cats into a an array of Animals if Dog and Cat extend Animal) and b) code reuse (a Dog can automatically reuse the methods of an Animal). These are two completely distinct, unrelated things unhappily forced into a marriage based on inheritance.

Comment: Polymorphism is Go is done through interfaces and only through interfaces. If you want to handle different things in a uniform way: Make the handling based on an interface and let the different things implement this interface. Not so different from tOOP. The large difference between Go and tOOP is in how you handle code reuse as there is _absolutely_ _no_ inheritance in Go.

Comment: If the sole difference between your Dog and your Animal are _additional_ fields and/or methods and everything "Animal-related" is a function of the Animal only: Embed an Animal into your Dog struct. Embedding in Go is a tiny syntactic sugar exposing the inner Animal in a Dog. You can even "override" a Animal method by providing it on the Dog. (Make sure you understand that this just provides reuse of code(=methods) provided by animal "as is" and this is different from polymorphism).

Comment: In Go you have other types of code re-use: Write a function! Functions are fast to write and easy to test. Write that function _after_ you write the code two or three times and are sure this is not a coincidence only.

Comment: @Volker  Thank you! This is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a common interface:

```
type Animal interface {
    DoSomething()
}

type A struct {
}

type B struct {
}

func (a *A) DoSomething() {
    fmt.Println("A")
}

func (b *B) DoSomething() {
    fmt.Println("B")
}

func test(some Animal) {
    some.DoSomething()
}

func main() {
    a := &A{}
    b := &B{}

    var all []interface{}
    all = append(all, a, b)

    for _, v := range all {
        v.(Animal).DoSomething()
    }
}
```

**Update**:

As have said @mkopriva, if you need to have common fields in both `struct` you can create a new `struct` and embed it in others:

```
type Animal interface {
    DoSomething()
}

type Common struct {
    Name string
}

type A struct {
    Common 
}

type B struct {
    Common 
}

func (a *Common ) DoSomething() {
    fmt.Println(a.Name)
}

func test(some Animal) {
    some.DoSomething()
}

func main() {
    a := &A{Common{Name: "a"}}
    b := &B{Common{Name: "b"}}

    var all []interface{}
    all = append(all, a, b)

    for _, v := range all {
        v.(Animal).DoSomething()
    }
}
```